# ISNULL() not working in update of table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, isnull

I have a stored procedure that includes a table variable which updates from other table variables. `ISNULL()` is not working in the below code. It returns the proper value if there is something in `TR.TotalRequestCnt`, but `NULL` if there is no value in the `TotalRequest` table for this column.

```sql
UPDATE @OutputTable
SET TotalRequestCount = ISNULL(TR.TotalRequestCnt, 0) 
FROM @TotalRequest TR
JOIN @OutputTable OT
ON TR.Document = OT.Document
```

Values of Document are identifying INTs (5577,5575, 5574).

`@TotalRequest` values are all INT:

```
5577        NULL    NULL
5575        NULL    NULL
5574        2       1
```

I have also tried using `COALESCE()` instead of `ISNULL()` to no success.

Comment: Please provide sample data for both table variables.

Comment: . . . including data types.

Comment: Also, show @OutputTable data before and after the update statement.  Show us all the column names.

Comment: My guess is that you are seeing null values in @OutputTable for all the rows where there is **no matching `Document`** in @TotalRequest.  If that is true, then if you change `join` to `right outer join` it might do what you want.

Comment: I also think you should be saying `Update OT` instead of `Update @OutputTable` because you have aliased it in the query. My guess is that if it *did* work it would update every row in the table, not just the ones joined.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

No update is being performed in the row at all because there are no values so `ISNULL` never has the chance to fire.